# Why a EDT violation happens?

Tags: java, edt

I started to use `CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager` to detect EDT violations.

It complains about:

```
partner = getParameter("partner",generatePartnerSelectionPanel(),Design.partnerSelectionDuration);
```

Because it does not like `generatePartnerSelectionPanel()` because it does not like `JPanel panel = new JPanel();` in this method. But I cannot find out why there should be a problem around that.

In more details, `generatePartnerSelectionPanel()` generates a JPanel (I do it not in the EDT) but then, in the `getParameter` I add the JPanel to the main JFrame and I do it in the EDT (using `invokeLater`).

So, why there should be a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An EDT violation doesn't mean something necessarily *did* go wrong, it means you tried to do a GUI related action on a thread other than the EDT (a situation where something *might* go wrong).

Creating a new Swing component is covered by "doing something GUI related", hence the warning about the violation.

This [forum has quite a discussion](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t707173-why-does-jdk-1-6-recommend-creating-swing-components-on-the-edt.html) on why it's not recommended to create Swing components on other threads.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this will happen if you create any GUI components in the thread handed to you in main.

Now, in reality nothing bad will ever happen as long as you don't modify it after you've realized it (`setVisible(true)` or `pack()` will realize a frame), BUT Sun found some edge case that they claim make it so this can cause a problem.

So to be perfectly correct have your main construct your first window *inside* an `invokeLater` or `invokeAndWait`.

Actually, I wonder if exiting your main thread right after the `invokeLater` might allow your entire app to exit (since the window almost certainly hasn't had time to come up yet)...  You might want to use `invokeAndWait` unless your main thread doesn't exit.

Answer (score 1):

Swing is thread-hostile. Even if a component is not realised, it may still access shared resources or call `EventQueue.invokeLater`. There was a period when it was widely stated that Swing components could be created off the, but that was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the `CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager` I've been using an Aspect Oriented solution to detect when any Swing components are constructed off of the EDT. This is an elegant way to troubleshooting EDT violations if you use AspectJ.

See this blog post for details:

[Debugging Swing, the final summary (from archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20110319000457/http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/02/16/debugging-swing-final-summary)

Comment: the link doesn't work anymore. do you have its new address?

Comment: Looks like Oracle broke the link. Sorry, I could not find a valid link.