# Swing components misplaced on JFrame when using Singleton

Tags: java, swing, singleton, jframe

Let's say I have a `JFrame` that is created through a singleton pattern like this :

```
private static Dist2PuncteFrame instance = null;

public static Dist2PuncteFrame getInstance() {

    if (instance == null)
        instance = new Dist2PuncteFrame();
    return instance;
}
```

I call it through a `JMenuItem` like this:

```
dist2PcteItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            dist2PcteFrame = Dist2PuncteFrame.getInstance();
            dist2PcteFrame.setSomeParameters(blablabla);
            dist2PcteFrame.init();
        }
    });
```

Nothing complicated. The problem occurs when I open the window the second time.
My close button and the 2 input labels seem to move (labels left/right, button up/down).

[image]

I have frames that are called the exact same way and they don't have this problem.
Anyone knows what seems to be the problem?
I am using NetBeans 7.1.

Comment: Possiby an EDT Violation? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727841/why-a-edt-violation-happens

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Without seeing your code, it's unlikely that someone can tell what's going on.

Comment: Yes, post your code - looks like you're building the GUI every time so you end up with multiple instances of the GUI controls inside the single Frame. Try temporarily removing the singleton check (comment out: "if (instance == null)" ) to verify this.

Comment: What does init() do? Does it add the controls? It must be doing something that affects the rendering

Comment: I've got it. My `init()` method initializes the components (`result = new JLabel()`, etc.) and calls the addListeners() and createLayout() methods. The solution is to add `getContentPane().removeAll()` before everything else in `init()`.